# Java - Possible to draw a basic force-directed undirected Graph (Vertices, Edges)?

Tags: java, graph, drawing

I am trying to create a class in Java that will extend another class called Graph.

The outline of the graph class is as follows:

- Graph constructor
- adjacent(int i, int j)
- addEdge, removeEdge methods
- addVertex, removeVertex methods
- neighbors method
- numOfEdges method
- averageDegree method
- girth method

I want to know if it possible to draw a very very basic force-directed undirected graph in Java using the graph class that I have made. I want my graph to be visually pleasing!

If so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

What is your question, exactly? If you ask whether your class contains enough information to allow applying a force-based layout, then obviously, the answer is no: you at least need to represent the position of the nodes ^^ (eg using additional x and y nodal attributes).

Regarding the algorithm itself, are you interested in the process of implementing it yourself, or just in the result: displaying your graph in a nice way? In the former case, you could start by having a look at seminal papers such as ([Fruchterman & Reingold '91](ftp://ftp.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/axel/papers/reingold:graph_drawing_by_force_directed_placement.pdf)) or ([Kamada & Kawai '89](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.387.7401&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). Both articles explicitly give the proposed algorithm. In the latter case, you could have a look at existing implementations, there're so many of them. Maybe the most convenient for you would be [Gephi](https://gephi.org)'s layout-related class, since this open source software ([available on GitHub](https://github.com/gephi/gephi)) is itself written in Java.

In any case, you can also have a look at the other SO posts related to this topic, such as [Kamada & Kawai graph layout algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386790/kamada-kawai-graph-layout-algorithm) or [Force-directed graphing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494452/force-directed-graphing/1494577#1494577).